# Can't get Google Map height to automatically resize when div is resized

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using AngularJS, jQuery UI (with a custom directive for resize), and Bootstrap. On my page, a Google Map appears in the top section, and a table will appear in the bottom section. As the user resizes the bottom section, I'd like the Google Map to automatically resize to take up the remaining space.

I've tried several different approaches including:

- Setting `html, body { height: 100%; width: 100% }` and `#mapCanvas { height: 100% }`.
- Using flexbox and flexgrow.
- Calculating the size of the top section after the bottom section is resized, and dynamically changing the height of the `#mapCanvas` element based on that.

But I haven't had luck with any of these. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Below is an example demonstrating the issue.

JSFiddle (in case the snippet area is obscured by the Google Maps API key warnings): https://jsfiddle.net/jmg157/9odt0hLn/

```js
function initMap() {
  let mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    minZoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(43, -81),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), mapOptions);
}

let app = angular.module("mapApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.directive('resizable', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      callback: '&onResize'
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.resizable({
        "handles": {
          "n": ".ui-resizable-n"
        }
      });
    }
  };
});

app.controller("MapAppController", function($scope) {
  initMap();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#mapCanvas {
  /*height: 100%;*/
  height: 60vh;
}

.ui-resizable-n {
  border-top: 5px solid grey;
}

.table {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="mapApp">
    <div ng-controller="MapAppController">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" resizable>
          <div class="ui-resizable-n ui-resizable-handle"></div>
          <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            Bottom Content Section
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You could use the `resize` event and set the map container height based on the resizable element height (in this case, the top section is resizable...). http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/dgsz4L0e/

Comment: @MrUpsidown Perfect! This solution works great. I just had to tweak the calculation a bit to account for a div I had at the top of the page. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the upper element to resizable and listening to the `resize` event and setting the map container height to be the resized element height.

```
app.directive('resizable', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      callback: '&onResize'
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.resizable();
      elem.on('resizestop', function(evt, ui) {
        if (scope.callback) {
          scope.callback();
        }
      });
      elem.on('resize', function(evt, ui) {

        // Set map container height based on resizable element height
        $('#map-canvas').height($('div[resizable]').height());
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Full working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/dgsz4L0e/).

Answer (score 0):

I have a menu-bar on the top of the map. When I added some geometries then they were hiding behind the menu-bar which I did not want. So I got the menu-bar height and then removed it from the height of the map. Now I applied this height for the map.

```
//Setting up map with initial properties
$scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(latCenter, longCenter),
    fullscreenControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

//Restricting the zoom levels for the user
var opt = { minZoom: 1, maxZoom: 16 };
$scope.map.setOptions(opt);

//removing the top menubar height
var newHeight = $('body').height() - 41 + 'px';
//setting up the map from 100% to the new height
$('#map').css('height', newHeight);
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to get the actual height of the table and use this code.

```
var newHeight = $('body').height();
$('#map').css('height', newHeight);
```

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: `$('body').height();` gets you the table height? OK.

Comment: yes it does and then we give the map the new height.

Comment: What about you provide a full working snippet then, so that we can see how your solution works?